# Nowhere padding or margin in the header

Tags: html, css

I have nowhere indent from the header, but I don't know how to fix it?

```
  <header class="page-header">
            <section class="logo">
                <i class="logo-img"> </i>
            </section>

        <section class="menu">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Правила</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тест</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Список смотрителей</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section class="profile-avatar">
            <img height="50px" width="50px" src="img/ava.png">

            <ul class="profile-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Профиль</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Выйти</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </header>
```

[image]

If I add clearfix to the header it gives to him more height..

Code is here  https://jsfiddle.net/tLtkmcy9/

## Right solution is to add **height** to class with the **float: right;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your `class="profile-avatar"` if you take him float right of it is not anymore like that you have to play with the height and it will be ok! try `height: 50px;`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code for the HTML mentioned below

```
style="position: relative;top: -4px;left: -4px;"
```

```
<section class="page-desc" style="
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px; ">
    <p class="caution"><a href="#">Перед тем как подавать заявку на смотрителя, Вы должны пройти тест!</a></p>
</section>
```